# A more effecient approach to a javascript / dom rendering issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, html-rendering

Apologies in advance for the lengthy explanation. I think this sketches it best! :P

Let's say I have 10 div's that were positioned absolute (css) on top of each-other. Each div contains several transparent png's that are also placed on top of each-other, together forming a visual whole. I only show 1 div at the time and the user can switch to the next div by clicking an arrow or button. This arrow/button contains a tag that tells me which is the next div to show so through javascript I hide all the div's and then show the appropriate one right after that.

Why is this slow in most browsers? Is there a better approach to do something like this? IE and Firefox seem to switch the div rather fast and smoothly, where as Chrome shows a delay. Here's an overview of the html and javascript:

HTML:

```
            <div id="div1" class="active generic">
                <img src="sample00.png" width="1000" height="564" class="a1" />
                <img src="sample01.png" width="1000" height="564" class="a2" />
                <img src="sample02.png" width="1000" height="564" class="a3" />
                <img src="sample03.png" width="1000" height="564" class="a4" />
                <img src="sample04.png" width="1000" height="564" class="a5" />
            </div>
            <div id="div2" class="generic">
                <img src="sample05.png" width="1000" height="564" class="a1" />
                <img src="sample06.png" width="1000" height="564" class="a2" />
                <img src="sample07.png" width="1000" height="564" class="a3" />
                <img src="sample08.png" width="1000" height="564" class="a4" />
                <img src="sample09.png" width="1000" height="564" class="a5" />
            </div>
```

and so on...

Javascript:

```
a++;
var gen = $('.generic');
var div = $('#div' + a);
gen.hide().removeClass('activeFrame');
div.show().addClass('activeFrame');
```

It's probably too vague for anyone to give a better solution. But if someone could explain to me why this would be slow on some browsers / lower end systems and how I might be able to remedy that, I could use that knowledge to think of something myself (or accept that it's just the way it is).

Comment: use chaining method style `$('.generic').hide().removeClass('active');`

Comment: It would probably be quicker to store $('.generic') and $('#div' + a) as variables to avoid going back to the DOM to get them twice each. Or chain things as the previous comment.

Comment: diEcho: I edited it and now use that. It doesn't really perform noticeably faster but of course it is better practice so :) And thanks dougajmcdonald, I will do that!

Comment: Any idea why it works much faster on IE? Is it because IE supposedly uses the video-card to render web pages?

Comment: Why not use one img element and just change the `src` property? Preload images first though, or use a sprite.

Answer (score 1):

there are a plenty of article on internet regarding jquery performance tips. Please read those. below is some of links

#### http://www.smashingmagazine.com/learning-javascript-essentials-guidelines-tutorials/

#### http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#harness-chaining

#### http://www.slideshare.net/AddyOsmani/jquery-proven-performance-tips-tricks

#### http://tomsbigbox.com/10-best-practises-for-jquery-beginners/